# Call comparison operators in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, call

i need to find out if the difference from differenceAB is the smallest:

```
smallestDifference3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallestDifference a b c
    | differenceAB < differenceBC < differenceAC = differenceAB
    | otherwise = differenceAB
  where differenceAB 
         | a < b = -(a - b)
         | otherwise    = a - b
        differenceBC
         | b < c = -(b - c)
         | otherwise    = b - c
        differenceAC
         | a < c = -(a - c)
         | otherwise    = a - c
```

but i get this error:

```
cannot mix `<' [infix 4] and `<' [infix 4] in the same infix expression
```

how to solve my problem? anybody know´s? greetingS!

Comment: I completely re-arranged your question. Probably a bit of an extreme edit, but your previous updates unfortunately stopped the original question from making sense. Also fixed this other problem about `differenceAB` etc. being functions.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of problems here.

You have 3 exactly identical **functions**. Probably you want values:

```
smallestDifference a b c = ....
  where
    diffAC = abs(a-c)
    diffAB = abs(a-b)
    diffBC = abs(b-c)
```

Now for the expression, you can't write

```
diffAC < diffAB < diffBC
```

since (<) is a non-associative operator. Which means you must write explicit parentheses:

```
(diffAC < diffAB) < diffBC
```

But this doesnt type check, because for the second (<) the left hand side is Bool, but the right hand side is Int. What you want is

```
(diffAC < diffAB) && (diffAB < diffBC)
```

i.e. if ac is lower then ab **and** ab is lower than bc

Comment: @user2999787: that's because of your other problem: `differenceAB` etc. shouldn't be functions but local values, as Ingo also explained already.

Comment: so i have to delete my three functions and add local value´s instead ?

Comment: could you show me sample code? i cant understand 100% what u mean..sorry

Comment: Just add the where clause shown above below your guards, aligned with the | and call the variables `differenceAB`etc. I have used a short form to save typing (you know Haskell is lazy)

Comment: Or you could use `abs (a-b)` instead of `differenceAB` it is shorter anyway, and don't write the where clause

Comment: i upadted again, but there is no sensefull result

Comment: you know where the bug is?

Comment: Now you have just removed the '=' from your functions? Why? If you insist on using them, you need this `differenceAB a b < differenceAC a c` but it's silly.

Comment: I told you before: differenceAC is a **function**. You can't compare functions. What exactly do you not understand here? Look, I am assuming that someone who does Haskell has at least read this: https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell/1-haskell-basics or something like it.

Comment: i did exactlöy the same way but they are not in scope now, i changed the code, you see?

Comment: You need to understand what is in scope when. The arguments a,b,c to your function `smallestDifference3` are only in scope in that function. Which is why I told you to define your diffAB and so on in a **where** clause, that introduces **local** definitions. But you do just not listen.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find the smallest difference, following will work.

`smallestdiff a b c = minimum [abs $ a-b, abs $ b-c, abs $a-c]`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as chaining operators in Haskell. You should use explicit logical operations:

```
smallestDifference3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
smallestDifference a b c
    | (differenceAB < differenceBC) && (differenceBC < differenceAC) = differenceAB
    | otherwise = differenceAB
```

BTW, your code is weird, you return `differenceAB` from both guard clauses. It is not clear what you want to achieve, so I cannot help further.

Comment: i updated, i want to return the result of the function, know what i mean?

Comment: i want to type in command ghci: "smallestdifference3 1 5 19" and output the smallest difference of these three(1 5 19) Integers :/ you know?